# How use externalDataSource option to write from Databricks to synapse?

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

while I was reading the documentation I came across this option "externalDataSource"

> A pre-provisioned external data source to read data from Azure Synapse. An external data source can only be used with PolyBase and removes the CONTROL permission requirement since the connector does not need to create a scoped credential and an external data source to load data

And in the note below it says

> externalDataSource is relevant only when reading data from Azure Synapse and writing data from Azure Databricks to a new table in Azure Synapse with PolyBase semantics You should not specify other storage authentication types while using externalDataSource

Is there any difference in performance when writing to synapse?

Also, I don´t know what is the input, in the documentation says

```
    df = spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<the-rest-of-the-connection-string>") \
  .option("tempDir", "abfss://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>") \
  .option("externalDataSource", "<your-pre-provisioned-data-source>") \
  .option("dbTable", "<your-table-name>") \
  .load()
```

"your-pre-provisioned-data-source"  should be the same name of "dbtalbe"?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any difference in performance when writing to synapse?

Various data loading techniques are supported by the Azure Synapse Analytics. Load the data using PolyBase is the quickest and most efficiently. The T-SQL language can be used with PolyBase, a data virtualization tool, to access external data kept in Azure Data Lake Storage.

To use this PolyBase you need to create external database to Azure Data Lake Store.

To create external database, you will need scoped credentials for `Azure Data Lake Store`:

```sql
-- Create a db master key.
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD='<EnterStrongPasswordHere>';

-- Create a database scoped credential.
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ADL_User
WITH
    IDENTITY = '<client_id>@<OAuth_2.0_Token_EndPoint>',
    SECRET = '<key>'
;
```

After creating scoped credential, you need to create External database to mention a piece of external Azure storage and provide the login information needed to access it.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <data_source_name>
WITH
(    LOCATION         = '<prefix>://<path>'
     [, CREDENTIAL = <database scoped credential> ]
     , TYPE = HADOOP
)
[;]
```

> "your-pre-provisioned-data-source" should be the same name of "dbtalbe"?

You can use above created external data source name in place of `"your-pre-provisioned-data-source"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so  if I want to write to a synapse table I should not use the "externalDataSource" option. But about using Polybase, I had read that COPY is better, could you tell me how true it is?

Comment: On Azure Synapse Analytics COPY is slower than Polybase.

Comment: So when I write from databricks is it better to specify to write it with POLYBASE? I know that when writing from databricks to synapse, a blobstorage is used where databricks writes first and then passes to synapse, so when I specify POLYBASE or COPY in databricks is it used in both environments? or synapse will always use polybase regardless of what I set up in databricks?